# How can get value from URL in php?

Tags: php, url

I want to get the value from URL using PHP, I could use following code,it's working in localhost, but not working in production server.

**sample.php**

```
<a href="report.php?id=<?php $a=5; echo $a; ?>">View</a>
```

**report.php**

```
 <?php
$id=$_GET['id'];

echo $id;

?>
```

This code outputs 5 in localhost, but in production server does not give the value.

Comment: Immediately hey? Please and thank-you never goes astray...

Comment: hire someone immediately

Comment: When you click the link and go to `report.php`, what does the URL query part look like?

Comment: try href="/report.php

Comment: well, if it does not display whatever you want, then an error should happen. so what is your error

Answer (score 0):

In my server test, the out is 5 in both localhost and server. I think the problem is mainly caused by you server/php config.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<a href="report.php?id=5">View</a>
```